# IPhone Objective-C only enable a button if NSTextfield is not blank

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a button that I only want enabled when a textfield is not blank. I have been trying to do this by implementing the following method, without any luck.

`- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{`

Is there another delegate method that I could implement that gets fired after the text is changed? In this method is there some way to tell what key is being pressed, if it's a delete or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check for `string.length == 0` and `range.length > 0;`.  This denotes a deletion.  However, what you really want is to just do the pending modification and then check that you still have a non-empty string.

Something like this (typed in, not compiled):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *testString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if( testString.length )
        myButton.enabled = YES;
    else
        myButton.enabled = NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: If you're going for brevity you can just do: myButton.enabled = testString.length; and lose 3 lines of code.

Comment: I'd be careful about assigning an integer to a BOOL. With one of the runtimes (and I can't remember if the iPhone is it), this'll cause the control to be enabled on odd lengths and disabled on even. Suggest myButton.enabled = testString.length > 0 instead.

Comment: Oh. And length isn't a property either, come to think of it. So it should be myButton.enabled = [testString length] > 0

Comment: Dot syntax != property.  It is syntactic sugar that allows calling of accessor methods.  Properties use dot syntax but are more than that (compiler generated accessors, etc.).

Comment: @BenLachman, I tried what you suggested and every other letter ended up disabling the button.  I agree, less code is sometimes nicer!  This code does what you were suggesting:

myButton.enabled = testString.length > 0;

Comment: Maybe I am just stupid, or just really tired, but does the `myButton.enabled` line go to the return as it is a boolean function expecting a boolean return value...

Comment: @JonWeinraub I've added the missing return value. It is not implicit.